# How can I adjust calibration figure size?

Tags: programming, qiskit

I'm hoping to obtain a larger picture of the calibration figure. The original command is

```
meas_fitter.plot_calibration()
```

I tried to use

```
meas_fitter.plot_calibration(figsize=(10,10))
```

but that doesn't work. How can I make it bigger? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you tried to recreate the plot of the calibration matrix [from this tutorial](https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/noise/3_measurement_error_mitigation.html). Which output a plot like something like below when you execute `meas_fitter.plot_calibration()`.

[image]

But you want the image above to be larger. If that is the case, then you can change the image size as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
meas_fitter.plot_calibration(ax)
```

Comment: Thanks so much:)

Comment: No problem! Glad I was able to help. :)